# Confusions about multi-class classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

I'm working on a 200-class classification task(but it's a little bit different, because there might be multiple 1's in the y vector) using a 4-layer fully-connected neural network. For most times y(label vector) contains one or two 1's, and that's where the problem is. When training, the model tends to predict all the labels as zero, even it should be 1.
Thus the accuracy is low(less than 99%, which is almostly worse than all-zero prediction). The activation function for each layer is sigmoid. Could you give me some advice to improve the model?

This is my loss function. The accuracy is low because when I predict all labels as 0, it'll get almost 99% accuracy.

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(-(sum_all - sum_one) / sum_all * tf.multiply(ys, tf.log(prediction)) - sum_one / sum_all * tf.multiply((one - ys), tf.log(one - prediction)), reduction_indices = [1])) sum_one indicates the number of 1's in the label. I implemented a weighting here.
```

Comment: I guess this question might be better migrated to crossvalidated stackexchange. But that's a comment for reviewers. @Garen Zhou, can you post the code you've used, in particular your loss function definition. Also, please clarify when you say the accuracy is less than 99%, does that mean it gets 98% accuracy? That seems quite good for most applications no?

Comment: This is my loss function. The accuracy is low because when I predict all labels as 0, it'll get almost 99% accuracy. `loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(-(sum_all - sum_one) / sum_all * tf.multiply(ys, tf.log(prediction)) - sum_one / sum_all * tf.multiply((one - ys), tf.log(one - prediction)), reduction_indices = [1]))` sum_one indicates the number of 1's in the label. I implemented a weighting here.

Comment: Multiple 1's in y make this a multi-label classification, and that maybe make use of a different loss function, suitable for multi-label task.

Comment: So your dataset contains 99% 0's as labels and 1% 1's? If this is the case then the answer becomes immediately obvious, such an imbalanced dataset will always produce this kind of result. Oversample your 1% class such that each training batch contains 50% 1's and 50% 0's, ignoring the fact that you'll have to duplicate your underrepresented class significantly.